# whenever i run my project, error "The requested resource is not available" occurs

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm following this tutorial to built a login page [(link)](http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/login-system-example-in-servlet.php) but i'm using "postgresql" for database.

I have only 2 columns in my table. One is `usr` and second one is `password`.
I am using `Tomcat7 server` in `Eclipse IDE`.
I changed `url, driver, database, name, password` only in `valid.java` page.

Please help...

**Output shows like :**
`HTTP Status 404 - /new/login
 type Status report
 message /new/login
 description The requested resource is not available.
 Apache Tomcat/7.0.70`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is the url you are trying? and what is the dynamic web application name you have given , is it same what you are using in your url?

Comment: url is "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/form","postgres","vijit1". And i'm using "Eclipse mars.2".

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have proper entry for `Login servlet` in `web.xml` you should mention full package structure of Login servlet class

For e.g for `class in src` folder `src\com\servlet\FirstServ.java`

**its entry should be like below in `web.xml`**

```
    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>FirstServ</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servlet.FirstServ</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>    
  <servlet-name>FirstServ</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FirstServ</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```

mention full package structure for `Login servlet` in `web.xml` inside `servlet-class tags`.

Tried same example and its worked.For implementing application as provided in [link](http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/login-system-example-in-servlet.php) then PFB screenshot of directory structure of eclipse.

[image]

Comment: I changed it as u say....but it occurs same error..

Comment: Try by proper clean-building project once and then restart. In eclipse go to Project menu >Clean > Build project.

Comment: @vijit find my updated above comment. try by clean build and check directory structures are proper and you are using same web.xml as its mentioned in your link

Comment: Yes i'm using same web.xml as mentioned in link. Can u plz tell me how many jar file r requied for it ???

Comment: No any additional jars required for me as I am not have SQL DB but running this mysql jar is required to have in lib. i have just created new Dynamic Web project. Only JRE System Library and Apache tomcat library as seen in attached screenshot above which is coming by default once you are creating Dynamic Web project. To create dynamic Web project through eclipse go to File > New >Project >Dynamic Web project(Inside web folder). Also try clean Project menu >Clean > Build . then run project on server like Right click on your project > Run As > Run on server then next next.

Comment: I am not connecting to SQL DB and As I don't have My sql jar its throwing me "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" error on console and I have set     boolean st =true; in Validate class checkUser method so its throwing error and its catched in same class and just printed over there so as I am setting flag as true its showing me welcome message.

Comment: there is no option of Clean > build.

Comment: in eclipse go to Project >Clean...> Select clean All projects option and select below Start a build immediately checkbox from that select build entire work-space option

Comment: finally i run that .....there was an error in mapping in web.xml page.

Comment: @Vijit okies great